# Read uploaded .csv file using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, oledb

I would like to know how to read a csv file which has been uploaded by a  control. Ive tried using OLEDB, but i get an exception. Something about that the file is read-only. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You'll probably get more help if you paste the entire exception message and stack trace.  And even more help if you paste the code you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the [FileHelpers library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/filehelpers/?_test=beta).
Here is an example of usage with a FileUpload control:

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]  // comma separated values
[IgnoreFirst(1)]        // first line is assumed to be the header
[IgnoreEmptyLines]      // ignore empty lines
class MyClass {

    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]
    public string FirstName;

    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]
    public string LastName;
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (!FileUpload1.HasFile) {
        // No CSV file selected
        return
    }
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream)) {
        FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(MyClass));
        foreach (MyClass entry in engine.ReadStream(sr)) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: MyClass is a data structure to which you want to parse your csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the specific error you are getting or what you've tried, I've used something like the following to read a CSV file in with OLEDB

```
string sCSVConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + PATHTOFILE + @";Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited(,)';";

using ( OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(sCSVConnectionString))
{
    connection.ConnectionString = sCSVConnectionString;
    connection.Open();

    using (DbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + FILENAME + "]";

        using (DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                // do something with the DataReader dr here.
            }

            dr.Close();
        }
    }

    connection.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used the [Fast CSV reader](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx) a couple of times and indeed it is fast.  This is what I use when faced with CSV files.

Good luck GJ